# paste0 and ifelse as a part of a pipe in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),b=c(6,7,8,9,10),c=c(3,NA,5,6,7))
```

> ```
>   a  b  c
> 1 1  6  3
> 2 2  7 NA
> 3 3  8  5
> 4 4  9  6
> 5 5 10  7
> ```

I would like to add a "string:" to every value of column c unless it is NA.

I thought of using:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(c) %>% ifelse(is.na(.),c,(paste0("string:"))
```

My desired output is:

```
  a  b  c
1 1  6  string:3
2 2  7  NA
3 3  8  string:5
4 4  9  string:6
5 5 10  string:7
```

Comment: `select()` removes columns. `mutate()` creates new columns or changes existing ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `stringr::str_c` with `transform/mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(c = str_c('string:',c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option

```
df <- within(df,c <- paste0(ifelse(is.na(c), "", "string:"),c))
```

yields

```
> df
  a  b        c
1 1  6 string:3
2 2  7       NA
3 3  8 string:5
4 4  9 string:6
5 5 10 string:7
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(c), c, paste0("string:", c)))

#  a  b  c        x
#1 1  6  3 string:3
#2 2  7 NA     <NA>
#3 3  8  5 string:5
#4 4  9  6 string:6
#5 5 10  7 string:7
```

which is similar to using `transform` in base R.

```
transform(df, c = ifelse(is.na(c),c,paste0("string:", c)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple option would be:

```
df$c <- ifelse(is.na(df$c), NA, paste0('string:', df$c))
```